# Rails zip array matching by column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two arrays and i'm using a zip method to join them together in a loop. I'm having an issue when a record doesn't exist in the zip method it throws out the order of the data.

For example:

**My view**

```
<% @temperature.zip(@rain).each do |temp, rain| %>
 <%= temp.site_no %> | <%= temp.temperature %> | <%= rain.present? ? rain.total_rain : '0' %>
<% end %>
```

Should display data in a manner of:

```
Site no | Temp | Rain
   1    |  20  |  10
   2    |  22  |  0
   3    |  18  |  3
```

But because site two doesn't exist in the @rain zip method it places the second row of data at the end. I have two variables as i'm accessing the rain total at 8am every day.

**Controller**

```
@temperature = Weather.select('DISTINCT ON(site_no) site_no, temperature, lat, long, timestamp').group(:site_no, :temperature, :lat, :long, : timestamp).order(: site_no).where('timestamp > ?', 7.days.ago)
@rain = Weather.select('site_no, SUM(rain) as total_rain').where('timestamp > ?', 7.days.ago).where('timestamp::time = ?', "08:00").group(:site_no)
```

So site 2 has no rain at 8am for any days selected, so therefore doesn't exist in the @rain variable. I've tried to match via conditionals by `site_no`, but still no luck.

**Schema**

```
create_table "weathers", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer "site_no"
 t.decimal "temperature"
 t.decimal "rain"
 t.datetime "timestamp"
 t.decimal "lat"
 t.decimal "long"
end
```

Comment: I think you're missing a Site model to bring all this together.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern. I've added the schema. No site model, site_no is part of the weathers table.

Comment: I suggest a Site model. It has methods to generate their 7 day averages. Pass Sites to your views instead. Or you pass a Hash where the key is the site_no: `{ 1: { temp: 20, rain: 10 }, 2: { temp: 22, rain: 0 }, 3: { temp: 18:, rain: 3 } }`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to approach is this setting up a two table system and grouping, joining and selecting aggregates.

```
# rails g model site name lat:decimal lon:decimal
class Site < ApplicationRecord
  # This is a truely ridiculous name
  # @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weathers_(band)
  has_many :weathers 

  def self.with_aggregates(from: 7.days.ago, to: Time.current)
    w = Weather.arel_table
    left_joins(:weathers)
      .select(
        :id,
        w[:rain].sum.as('total_rain'),
        w[:temperature].average.as('average_temperature'),
        w[:temperature].maximum.as('high_temperature'),
        w[:temperature].minimim.as('low_temperature')
      )
      .group(:id)
      .where(weathers: { timestamp: from..to })
  end
end
```

```
# for the love of god use the correct terms 
# Observation or Forecast instead of abusing the english language
class Weather < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site # Use `site_id` instead of `site_no`.
end
```

This will let you simple display it without zipping anything as you're actually doing it right and letting the database do the number crunching.

```
<% Site.with_aggregates.each do |site| %>
 <%= site.id %> | <%= site.average_temperature %> | <%= site.total_rain %>
<% end %>
```